# ¿Como cambiar de imagen dependiendo de la option de un select en ASP .net?

Tags: javascript, java

tengo un formulario que lo comprendren varios select cuyas opciones se cargan directamente desde la base de datos. Este formulario esta en una vista en el cual yo armo una puerta con las caracteristicas que se encuentran en los combos y la imegen del resultado se muestra en un lateral de la vista. Mi pregunta es, ¿Como puedo hacer para que la imagen se vaya cambiando en tiempo real dependiendo de cada especificacion? Yo tengo una carpeta de imagenes con todas las posibles combinaciones.
Esta es la vista.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buacando una solucion me encontre con este codigo, pero en realidad no se como adaptarlo.

```js
function cargarProvincias() {
    var array = ["Cantabria", "Asturias", "Galicia", "Andalucia", "Extremadura"];
    array.sort();
    addOptions("provincia", array);
}


//Función para agregar opciones a un <select>.
function addOptions(domElement, array) {
    var selector = document.getElementsByName(domElement)[0];
    for (provincia in array) {
        var opcion = document.createElement("option");
        opcion.text = array[provincia];
        // Añadimos un value a los option para hacer mas facil escoger los pueblos
        opcion.value = array[provincia].toLowerCase()
        selector.add(opcion);
    }
}



function cargarPueblos() {
    // Objeto de provincias con pueblos
    var listaPueblos = {
      cantabria: ["Laredo", "Gama", "Solares", "Castillo", "Santander"],
      asturias: ["Langreo", "Villaviciosa", "Oviedo", "Gijon", "Covadonga"],
      galicia: ["Tui", "Cambados", "Redondella", "Porriño", "Ogrove"],
      andalucia: ["Dos Hermanas", "Écija", "Algeciras", "Marbella", "Sevilla"],
      extremadura: ["Caceres", "Badajoz", "Plasencia", "Zafra", "Merida"]
    }
    
    var provincias = document.getElementById('provincia')
    var pueblos = document.getElementById('pueblo')
    var provinciaSeleccionada = provincias.value
    
    // Se limpian los pueblos
    pueblos.innerHTML = '<option value="">Seleccione un Pueblo...</option>'
    
    if(provinciaSeleccionada !== ''){
      // Se seleccionan los pueblos y se ordenan
      provinciaSeleccionada = listaPueblos[provinciaSeleccionada]
      provinciaSeleccionada.sort()
    
      // Insertamos los pueblos
      provinciaSeleccionada.forEach(function(pueblo){
        let opcion = document.createElement('option')
        opcion.value = pueblo
        opcion.text = pueblo
        pueblos.add(opcion)
      });
    }
    
  }
  
 // Iniciar la carga de provincias solo para comprobar que funciona
cargarProvincias();
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td align=right>Provincia:</td>
      <td align=left colspan=3>
          <!-- Añadido onchange para cargar los pueblos -->
          <select name="provincia" id="provincia" onchange="cargarPueblos();">
              <!-- Hay que terminar los options -->
              <!-- 
                   Eliminado de value la llamada a la función,
                   si eso funciona lo desconocía, y aunque 
                   lo haga es totalmente innecesario, 
                   lo correcto es usar el evento onchange 
                -->
              <option value="">Seleccione una Provincia...</option>
          </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>                    
      <td align=right>Pueblo:</td>
      <td align=left colspan=3>
          <select name="pueblo" id="pueblo">
              <!-- Hay que terminar los options -->
              <!-- 
                   Eliminado de value la llamada a la función,
                   si eso funciona lo desconocía, y aunque 
                   lo haga es totalmente innecesario, 
                   lo correcto es usar el evento onchange 
                -->
              <option value="">Seleccione un Pueblo...</option>
          </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Intentaste algo? esto no parece algo complicado, donde tuviste problemas?

Comment: Hace dias vi un codigo js que tal vez pudiera ayudarme, pero no se como adaptarlo a esto, por eso vengo pidiendo a ver si hay otra forma de hacerlo

Comment: si se peude hacer que cosa? que codigo viste? trataste de adapatarlo?